# Authorize.net DPM -- perform server side processing in servlet rather than jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, authorize.net, dpm

I'm currently working with a test account on Authorize.net and am utilizing their Direct Post Method form to submit transactions directly to their gateway without additional server-side processing on my end.  My application is a basic jsp webapp sitting on top of Apache Tomcat 7.

Per the instructions provided on their [Java Quick Start Guide](http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/java/) I have set up 3 files to: 1) take in user input, 2) relay the response, and 3) process and display output.

Truth be told, I don't really need to display an output to the user.  Instead, I would like to thoroughly process the response that Authorize.net sends me.  The sample code they provide explicitly accounts for this in the relay_response.jsp file:

```
String receiptPageUrl = "http://MERCHANT_HOST/order_receipt.jsp";
...
net.authorize.sim.Result result = net.authorize.sim.Result.createResult(apiLoginId,
 MD5HashKey, request.getParameterMap());
// perform Java server side processing...
// ...
// build receipt url buffer
StringBuffer receiptUrlBuffer = new StringBuffer(receiptPageUrl);
...
...
document.location = "<%=receiptUrlBuffer.toString()%>";
```

However, it looks like they want me to perform the processing in the jsp, while I would rather perform this work on the back end using a Java servlet.  I've tried to accomplish this using 2 methods, neither of which work quite as I want.

**Attempt 1)** I replaced the 'order_receipt.jsp' tag with a url to another jsp, which subsequently submits a form to a servlet, passing all request parameters.

```
String receiptPageUrl = "http://<my_server's_ip_address>/another.jsp";
```

The problem with this approach is that in the initial forward from relay_response.jsp all of the parameters are passed via GET and appear in the URL, which I can't allow.

**Attempt 2)** Rather than forwarding the results to another jsp, I created a form right inside relay_response.jsp and tried to submit the form with the results passed as a request parameter.

```
<form id='myform' method='post' action="servlet_action" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
  <input id='params' type='hidden' name='params' value='<%= paramsMap %>'/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("myform").submit();
</script>
```

The problem here is that although the browser displays my relay_response.jsp file, the value of document.location.hostname is test.authorize.net, so it doesn't recognize my action since that resides on my server rather than on authorize.net's server.

Alternatively, I have tried setting the action on the form to be the full url of my server and servlet action:

```
<form id='myform' method='post' action="http://<my_server's_ip_address>/webapp/servlet_action" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```

But I get a warning (at least in Firefox) saying that the data is not being transmitted over a secure connection: "Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party."

How can I pass the results of the transaction from relay_response.jsp to my Java servlet without exposing the parameters being passed to the user?  Should I be using https?  And why is document.location.host pointing to authorize.net rather than my relay_response.jsp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend suggested 2 solutions for the initial question I posted, one of which I have verified.

**Solution 1:**
Simply redirect the initial form to servlet rather than to relay_response.jsp.  Then the servlet can redirect to another jsp as apporpriate.  I have verified that this works with Authorize.net DPM.

**Solution 2:**
Inside the scriptlet in relay_response.jsp, make a call to a Java class that actually handles the logic.  You don't have to expose or write any Java code inside the scriptlet, but rather just invoke the class and call a few methods.  You can pass the response parameter map as the argument to the method.  I suppose the class you invoke could even be a proper servlet, though mixing these up might not be good form.